# How I can do this powershell script better?

Tags: powershell

When I move FenrirFS profile to another, paths in directories become wrong.
So I decided to make a ps script to resolve it.

```
$wdir = "files"       # constant part of path
$path = $PSScriptRoot # path to script
$pfix = "Target="     # prefix of path

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.alias | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Select -Expand Name

foreach ($file in $files) 
{
    $filec = Get-Content $file
    $nlin = 0         # counter of line

    foreach ($line in $filec) 
    {
        if($line.Contains($pfix)) 
        {
            $nline = $pfix + $path + '\' + $wdir + ($line -split $wdir)[1]
            $filec[$nlin] = $filec[$nlin].replace($line,$nline)
            $filec | Set-Content $file
            break
        }
    $nlin++ 
    }
}
```

It's work, but I have a lot of files, which I should replace.
And `$filec | Set-Content $file` a little bit dumby, cuz I need to replace only one line.
Example of file:

```
Target=E:\home\prj\polygon\ps\files\NoDigital\godTech_2.JPG
DisplayName=godTech_2.JPG
WorkDir=
Arguments=
ShowCmd=0
```

ps script is located in the directory with aliases.

p.s. powershell 5.1

Comment: Please show us (part of) such a file containing the line to replace and an example of the desired output

Comment: all what i want is: 
`Target=E:\home\prj\polygon\ps\files\NoDigital\godTech_2.JPG`

edit to:
`Target=E:\"new_directory_to_profile"\files\NoDigital\godTech_2.JPG`

Comment: "$filec | Set-Content $file a little bit dumby, cuz I need to replace only one line" - no, this is in fact the right way to go about it - the underlying file system does not know what a "line" is, the file is just one long string of bits on disk. If you want a code review, feel free to post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the much faster `switch` for that:

```
$wdir = "files"       # constant part of path
$path = $PSScriptRoot # path to script
$pfix = "Target="     # prefix of path

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter '*.alias' -File | ForEach-Object {
    $content = switch -Regex -File $_.FullName {
        "^$pfix"  { 
            $oldPath = ($_ -split '=', 2)[-1].Trim()
            $childPath = Join-Path -Path $wdir -ChildPath ($oldPath -split $wdir, 2)[-1] 
            # output the new path
            "$pfix{0}" -f (Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath $childPath)
        }
        default { $_ }
    }
    $content | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName -Force
}
```

Comment: this works nicely, but what does switch mean in this context?

Comment: @KirillMoskalew the switch loops through the file line-by-line and does a tegex comoare on each. All this high-speed